# rewriting an iOS app to work on both iOS and Mac-- how to organize controller code?

Tags: iphone, macos, ios, portability, viewcontroller

I have an iOS app that I am rewriting to work on both Mac and iOS.  I have my views working reasonably well, but everything is static at the moment.

What do I typically do with my view controller code?  In the iOS-only app, it is typically a bunch of stuff that says things like "if the user touches here, do that."

I've found the hitTest: method.  So I'm pretty sure I can write everything so it works.  I guess my question is more organizational.  Ideally, I would want to set things up so that the code that is currently in UIViewController subclasses would work on both platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to make the UIViewController code work on both platforms. The Mac doesn't have UIKit, and iPhone doesn't have AppKit.

What you really want to do at this point is have all of your networking, math and logic code in external classes. Normally subclasses of NSObject. Then, all you have to do is write code that calls these classes within your view controllers.

You're going to face one further challenge though - I don't think that you can have an app run on iPhone and Mac from one Bundle. When you compile your app, you *normally* compile to a specific processor. The Mac runs on Intel/PowerPC, and iPhone runs on Arm. You're going to have to fiddle with build targets etc. endlessly.

I would suggest maintaining two separate projects, and putting the aforementioned logic classes in a shared location and making sure that when you import them you don't choose the 'Copy to group destination folder' option. This way, any edits you make to the iPhone version of the code carries accross to the Mac version and vice-versa.

Happy coding,

Zane